# Order SQL result with point system

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to get my SQL result to be ordered by a certain 'point-system'. For every field that's filled in, the search result gets a certain amount of points. At the end of my SQL I add the following ORDER BY - code, however, if I change one of the '1'-numbers to a higher number, the search result order isn't changed. Why wouldn't that work? (Changed the bedrijfslogo-case to 9 in this example):

Thanks guys!

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY

case when ID is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when username is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when password is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when voornaam is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when achternaam is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when telefoonnummerP is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when emailP is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when functie is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsslogan is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfslogo is not null then 9 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsfoto is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsfoto2 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsfoto3 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsfoto4 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsomschrijving is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsspecialiteiten is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when bedrijfsgeschiedenis is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when openingstijden is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when kvk is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when straatnaam is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when huisnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when postcode is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when plaats is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when nevenvestigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when telefoonnummer is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when fax is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when email is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when website is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when twitter is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when facebook is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when youtube is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when linkedin is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when hoofdrubriek is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when subrubrieken is not null then 1 else 0 end + 
case when merken is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when diensten is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when productsoorten is not null then 1 else 0 end +
case when brancheverenigingen is not null then 1 else 0 end

 DESC";
```

Comment: If you display your calculated points value, does it change? Maybe your 'bedrijfslogo' value is not null, but 0 for missing results?

Comment: It's a MYSQL database, how can I display this result? Since I'm not saving the number in a variable?

Comment: 1. Normalise your data. Any time you see columns named xx1, xx2, etc alarm bells should start ringing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bedrijfslogo is empty in the table? :)

If you add the casing to a view instead it might be easier to find the error.

```
create view myView as 
select *, (CASE when ID is not null then 1 else 0 end + ... n) AS SortPoints
from table 
GO
select * from myView order by SortPoints desc
```